# R sum using group_by, select groups with large sum, then repeat sum using different group_by

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, summarize

I have a working solution to this problem, but I'm curious if there are ways to do this more efficiently than I did.

I have a dataframe that looks like below:

```
df <- data.frame("Factor1" = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4), rep("C", 4), rep("D", 4)),
                 "Factor2" = c(rep(c(rep("a", 2), rep("b", 2)), 4)),
                 "Value" = c(c(1:4), c(21:24), c(11:14), c(41:44)))
```

I first summed all `Value` for each `Factor1` to identify which `Factor1` has the largest sum of `Value`, then select the top `n` (2 in this example) sum of `Value` like below:

```
df2 <- df %>% group_by(Factor1) %>%
           summarise(Factor1.sum = sum(Value)) %>%
           arrange(desc(Factor1.sum)) %>%
           top_n(n=2) %>% ungroup()
```

Now that I identified `B` and `D` as the top two `Factor1` with the largest sum of `Value`, I would again like to calculate the sum of `Value`, but this time grouping by both `Factor1` and `Factor2`, like below.

```
df3 <- subset(df, Factor1 %in% df2$Factor1) %>%
          group_by(Factor1, Factor2) %>%
          summarise(Factor2.sum = sum(Value))
```

This gives me just what I want, but I need to create extra files (`df2` and `df3`), and I'm wondering if there's some function in the `dplyr` package (or really any package) that I'm unaware of that will make this process simpler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a shorter variation of the same thing, using `count` as a shortcut for `group_by` & `summarize`, and `left_join` to take the result of the first step as the list of Factor1's for the second part.

```
count(df, Factor1, wt = Value, sort = TRUE) %>% 
  slice(1:2) %>%
  left_join(count(df, Factor1, Factor2, wt = Value, name = "Factor2.sum"))


Joining, by = "Factor1"
  Factor1   n Factor2 Factor2.sum
1       D 170       a          83
2       D 170       b          87
3       B  90       a          43
4       B  90       b          47
```